# SEVERE:Memory usage is low, parachute is non existent, your system may start failing

Tags: tomcat, memory

I tried to install mifos in my server , Installed apache tomcat, also add ssl certificate to it,
Then i access it via my web browser gives an error.
Displays the Error message shown below.

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

And my apache log files shows below.

Mar 5, 2015 6:17:25 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint checkParachute
SEVERE: SEVERE:Memory usage is low, parachute is non existent, your system may start failing.
Mar 5, 2015 6:17:35 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint checkParachute
SEVERE: SEVERE:Memory usage is low, parachute is non existent, your system may start failing.
Mar 5, 2015 6:17:45 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint checkParachute
SEVERE: SEVERE:Memory usage is low, parachute is non existent, your system may start failing.
Mar 5, 2015 6:17:55 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint checkParachute
SEVERE: SEVERE:Memory usage is low, parachute is non existent, your system may start failing.
Mar 5, 2015 6:18:05 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint checkParachute
SEVERE: SEVERE:Memory usage is low, parachute is non existent, your system may start failing.
Mar 5, 2015 6:18:15 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint checkParachute
SEVERE: SEVERE:Memory usage is low, parachute is non existent, your system may start failing.
Mar 5, 2015 6:18:25 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint checkParachute
SEVERE: SEVERE:Memory usage is low, parachute is non existent, your system may start failing.

I don't know what the reason behind this error .. How can be solve this My server have 512 mb RAM

Answer (score 11):

This error log related to parachute is kind of a funny warning given by the developers saying that "system is going to break and I'm going to use my parachute". This means that your application is having a memory leak and JVM will go OOM soon. You need to profile your application and see what is causing this issue.

Comment: Can you explain how to profile an application? I am facing similar issue in my application when the resultant query response is huge. But this has happened over night without any code changes.